# Where to add custom methods for controller in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller called `bookmarks_controller`

It has all RESTful actions.

My `new.html.erb` has 4 fields

1. Url
2. Title
3. Descripion
4. Thumbnail url

I have a `fetch button` right next to `url` field. When the user click fetch button I need to fetch title, content and populate it in the form.

This feature require some additional methods. So I need to define some additional methods.

But i'm confused since I have no idea where to add those methods.

Some says helper methods defined in `bookmarks_helper` only available in views and not in controllers.

So what is the proper way to add my custom methods for controllers?

Comment: It's sounds you're saying about another action. If so, you should place it as a public method in your controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom action in bookmarks_controller as

```
#bookmarks_controller.rb

  def fetch_bookmark 
    #code to fetch bookmark 
  end
```

modify the routes.rb file

```
#routes.rb
resources :bookmarks do
  collection do
    get :fetch_bookmark
  end
end
```

and then call the action from new.html.erb

```
<%= link_to fetch_bookmark_bookmarks_path, remote: true %>
```

hoe this helps